# need custom login functionality in windows service c# while installation

Tags: c#, windows-services

I need such functionality in one of my windows service (c#) to ask user for their unique login name and password (these login are used to fetch some data from database and will used to show notification on timely based). Service will ask it while installation of windows service, means its not local service or local system or network service

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this Guide on MSDN: [How to: Specify the Security Context for Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0x72fzyf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Just set the `Account` attribute to `User` in the last step.

But I am not sure, if it is possibile to

> show notification

with only the windows service.

Normally, a Windows service cannot interact with the user interface. You may also need to develop a normal application that will be launched when the user logs in.